# URL Redirect does not appear in catalog

Tags: catalog, url, seo, url-rewrite, ee-1.13.0.2

i've created a url redirect for when the user types `womens/clothing/activate/[ITEM]` they can get `catalog/product/view/id/[ITEMID]/category/[CATID]`

when i use my new url redirect it works fine however when i go into the catalog where the item is i'm the internal url (`catalog/product/view/id/[ITEMID]/category/[CATID]`) instead of my rewrite, in the template i use `getProductUrl()`

i am wondering if i'm missing a step to get my products in the catalog view to have my url redirect over the internal one

Comment: HI, please clarify: When you say you get the 'internal' url, are you getting a url of such: catalog/product/view/id/[ITEMID]/category/[CATID] or a url that is the [URL_KEY].html of the product?

Comment: @ProxiBlue the first one, `catalog/product/view/id/[ITEMID]/category/[CATID]`, edited my question to make it clear

Comment: Hi, well that's not right. When a product is created, you can set the url-key, which will then be the 'seo friendly' url used in the frontend. WHen the product saves, magento creates the url-rewrite for you. You should have no need to go create 'nice urls' your self. There are possible reasons why that is not working for you. One could be that your url rewrite table has been wiped clean. Try and rebuild the url-rewrite index. ALso if you swap back to the default mgento theme do you get the same issue of the ugly url links? If not, then the issue is in your theme.